# Can't set property with same name as deleted attribute

Tags: python, properties

I've been trying for a while now to understand how @property works in python. I have looked for an answer by reading similar questions on this site, but it's still something related to the subject that I can't put my finger on how it works. For example the following situation:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'x'
    del self.name

  @property
  def name(self):
    return 'y'

my_class = MyClass()
print my_class.name # AttributeError: can't set attribute (self.name = 'x')
```

Why doesn't this work? As far as I understand you cannot set a property with the same name as an existing attribute that's why you should prefix it with `_` so `self._name` in my case, but I am already deleting self.name so why it still matters? Or is python not executing in the order I assume it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Any* access to `self.name` in `__init__` interacts with your property. You are not bypassing the property here.

Your property doesn't define a setter or a deleter, so assignment to `self.name` or deleting with `del self.name` is not allowed.

If you add a setter or deleter, the code in `__init__` would work:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'x'
        del self.name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        del self._name
```

I changed the property to use a different instance attribute, named `_name` to not interfere with the property itself. `self._name` is not a property, so you can set and delete it directly.

The full technical explanation is that a `property` object is a [descriptor object](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and a specific one at that. It is a *data descriptor*, which means that it is used before any instance attributes, always.

Regular non-data descriptors (like functions, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` objects), only have a `__get__` method. A data descriptor also defines at least a `__set__` or `__delete__` method. When Python looks up an attribute on an instance, the following searches happen:

1. Look for a data descriptor on the class (and bases)
2. Look for an attribute on the instance
3. Look for an attribute on the class (and bases), including non-data descriptors.

When you try to access `self.name`, you are looking for an attribute on `self`. Python finds the `name` property on the class, which is a data descriptor. So step one is used here, and `MyClass.name.__get__(self, MyClass)` is used to (indirectly) call your `name` function.

When trying to assign to `self.name`, `MyClass.name.__set__(self, newvalue)` is called, and for `del self.name`, `MyClass.name.__delete__(self)` is called. If you didn't define a setter or a deleter function in your class, the default action for a `property` object is to instead raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, implementing either or both of `__set__` and `__delete__` will cause a descriptor to be considered a data descriptor.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, the Howto simplified it; I should have consulted the [data model reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The property doesn't come into existence after `__init__` - it already exists before `__init__` is called. When you try to do

```
self.name = 'x'
```

You call the `name` property's `__set__`, which `AttributeError`s since you never defined a setter.

When you call

```
del self.name
```

You (would) call the `name` property's `__delete__` (if you reached the line at all). This would also `AttributeError`, since you define no deleter.